# Free group of a group

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, free-groups

I have a doubt about something: if $G$ is a group, what can we say about the free group ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ of $U(G)$, where $U$ is the forgetful functor from $Grp$ to $Set$?

I'm confused because if I'm not wrong: every group is a quotient of a free group by some relations, so when one "forgets" about the group structure of $G$:

- do we forget about these relations (in which case one would not recover $G$ by taking the free group over $U(G)$ in general)
- or are these relations actual equalities in the carrier set (e.g. if we have the group relation $ab=c$, then $ab$ and $c$ are really the same element in the carrier set), in which case I have the impression that ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ is isomorphic to $G$?

I really feel like there's something wrong:

1. on the one hand, I suppose that ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ shouldn't be isomorphic to $G$ in general (and that to recover $G$ from ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ one would need to "evaluate" the lists of elements of $U(G)$ that are in ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ with the group operation of $G$)
2. but on the other hand, I feel like the group relations are actual equalities in the carrier set, so that taking the free group over this carrier set should yield a group isomorphic to the original one

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: No, one does not forget the relations. If you present a group by generators and relations you are still describing some set (namely a certain quotient of a free group) and that set is the underlying set $U(G)$. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ can be presented by a single generator with no relations. $U(\mathbb{Z})$ is a countable set, and so the free group on $U(\mathbb{Z})$ is the free group on countably many generators.

Comment: Thanks! Simple yet effective example, how had I not seen that? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, $\mathrm{Free}(U(G)) \neq G$. For example, if $G$ is the trivial group, then $U(G)$ is a one element set, so $\mathrm{Free}(U(G)) \cong \mathbb Z.$ In general, $\mathrm{Free}(U(G))$ is much larger than $G$.

Another example. Let $G=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z=\{a,b\}$, equipped with a binary operation $ab=ba=b$, $aa=bb=a$. Then  $U(G)=\{0,1\}$, just as a set. In $\mathrm{Free}(U(G))$, the same multiplication structure does not hold. Every element of $\mathrm{Free}(U(G))$ is a string of symbols taken from the list
$$
a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}. 
$$
where the only relations that hold are $aa^{-1}$ and $bb^{-1}$ are equal to the identity.

Comment: Thank you! So we can get back $G$ from ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ by quotienting by your equations ($ab=ba=b$ and $aa=bb=a$) again I suppose?

Comment: @Cooke4 No you can't get back $G$ from $\operatorname{Free}(U(G))$ in general. For example both $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_4$ have an underlying set of $4$ elements, so the free groups $\operatorname{Free}(U(\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2))$ and $\operatorname{Free}(U(\mathbb Z_4))$ are isomorphic. Broadly speaking, $\operatorname{Free}(U(G))$ is only telling "I'm the free group on $\operatorname{Card}(U(G))$ elements", but the multiplicative law of $G$ is _a priori_ beyond recovery.

Comment: @Pece Thanks for you answer! I see, but then if you quotient ${\rm Free}(U(G))$ by the appropriate relations, can't you recover $G$?

Comment: @Cooke4 Yes, but you have to know the relation somehow, which is pretty much the same as knowing the group. Categorically speaking, $\operatorname{Free}$ is left adjoint to $U$, so you have a counit morphism $\epsilon_G:\operatorname{Free}(U(G)) \to G$ and the normal subgroup generated by the "appriopriate relations" is $\ker (\epsilon_G)$.

Comment: @Pece Oh I see, and then by quotienting by the kernel of the counit you get back $G$ I guess! Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: I have to nitpick: if $X$ is an infinite set, then $\mathrm{Free}(X)$ has the same cardinality as $X$. In particular, if $G = \mathrm{Free}(X)$, then there does exist an isomorphism $\mathrm{Free}(U(G)) \cong G$. However, you would be correct to point out that the counit is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks for pointing this out!